# How do I trace a SELECT query using profiler

Tags: sql-server-2008, trace, sql-server-profiler

I wanted to trace a `Select` query that one of the software runs to get data and generate a report. Can someone help me how to use profiler to trace select queries? Sorry I am new and have never used profiler.

I have written my own queries to fetch the data but wanted to see what query this particular software runs

Thanks!

Comment: does the software you are trying to debug run on a specific host?

Comment: yeah i am running it on sql server 2008R2 on my laptop